# POST Form & Slim PHP

Tags: php, slim

I am hoping someone can help me. I have Slim installed and working. The problem is I have an HTML form that submits to a routed URL and it says "404 page not found" but if I manually go to this page without submitting the form it works fine. If I use GET it also works fine when submitting the form.

My Form on /store routing

```
<form action='../checkout/demo' method='POST'>
    <input name='fullname' id='fullname' type='text' placeholder='Fullname'>
    <input name='email' placeholder='Email Address' type='text'>
    <input name='address1' placeholder='Address' type='text'>
    <input name='city' placeholder='City' type='text'> 
    <input name='state' placeholder='State' type='text'> 
     <input name='zip' placeholder='Zip/Postal Code' type='text'>
    <button type='submit'>Pay for my Items Now!</button>
</form>
```

My Router

```
require "Slim/Slim.php"; 
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader(); 
$router = new \Slim\Slim();  

$router->get("/store/:storeUrl", function ($storeUrl) {
    //This just adds the form to this url
    $controller = new Controller();
    $controller->mainStore($storeUrl); 
}); 
$router->get("/checkout/:storeUrl", function ($storeUrl) use ($router)            {
    echo "string"; 
}); 
$router->run();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Probably `action='../checkout/demo'` is pointing wrong. Where is this form-file located? Is it a typo with ../checkout/demo .. You meant ../checkout/demo.php ?

Comment: in `action='../checkout/demo'` give the full path not `../` . Also put the extension of `demo` file too there.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: The form goes to the correct page but it says the page is not found. If I manually go to the url it finds the address. I think the problem is something to do with Slim. If I submit the form using GET it works as well but post does not work.

Comment: `../checkout/demo` implies that "demo" is a folder and must contain an index file. So try `../checkout/demo/index.php`.

Comment: This did not work but thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the help!

I simply got it working by changing:

```
$router->get("/checkout/:storeUrl", function ($storeUrl) use ($router)   {
    echo "string";
    print_r($_POST);
});
```

to

```
$router->post("/checkout/:storeUrl", function ($storeUrl) use ($router) {
    echo "string";
    print_r($_POST);
});
```

Slim php was looking for a GET from a form and not a post.

Comment: *Hm...* I had a feeling about that earlier and should have mentioned that from the *get-go*.